# Remove spaces from a string, special characters and convert it to lowercase

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I need to format a string for comparison purpose.
Lets say we have 
**Multiple Choice**
I want to convert it to
**multiplechoice**
So white spaces removed, any special characters removed and lowercase.

I need to do this in SAPUI5 while comparing a value which I get from a model.

```
if (oCurrentQuestionModel.getProperty("/type") === "multiple choice")
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
var str = "Multiple Choice";
var strLower = str.toLowerCase();

strLower.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t9dmo1o2/).

**The Regex**

`\s` is the regex for "whitespace", and `g` is the "global" flag, meaning match all `\s` (whitespaces).

Comment: The regex could be improved by replacing `\s` with `\W` (case sensitive!) since loki also asked for removal of special characters. `\W` catches everything except `[0-9A-Za-z_]`

Answer (score 4):

```
function cleaner(str) {

    if (str) {

        var strLower = str.toLowerCase();
        return strLower.replace(/\W/g, '');

    }

    return false;

}
```